# Angularjs module loading error

Tags: angularjs

I am trying to execute the simplest angular piece of code that is as follows. I have defined `ng-app="budgetTracker"` in the `div` tag. Whenever I try to execute the html, it gives me the following error:

```
Uncaught Error: [$injector:modulerr] http://errors.angularjs.org/1.2.26/$injector/modulerr?p0=budgetTracker&p1=E…gleapis.com%2Fajax%2Flibs%2Fangularjs%2F1.2.26%2Fangular.min.js%3A18%3A387)
```

Code:

```
(function() {

    var app = angular.module("budgetTracker", []);

    app.directive("categories", function(){
        return {

        //User Attribute directives for mixin behavior such as a tooltip, else mostly use element directives
        //Directive definition object - a configuration that defines how a directive is going to behave
            restrict: 'E', // we are declaring a new html element
            templateUrl : 'js/templates/categories.html' // url of the template to be injected
        };
    });


});
```

Would anyone know why? I am pointing to the google cdn for angular and I am also including the app.js file in the head tag.

Comment: The thing in the error message is a clickable URL; click it for more detailed information, and paste the full link here. Right now it's truncated and not very helpful.

Comment: try `ng-app="budget-tracker"`

Comment: You shouldn't need to enclose your angular module inside a (function(){}) call.

Swap out your angular.min.js for angular.js so that you can get the full error, then let us know what it says.

Comment: Yes. Actually there isn't any need to wrap the app.js code inside (function(){}). But as the function is not getting executed, that is a possible reason of module not found error. So I have just modified the code to execute the function.

Answer (score -1):

I guess you are missing to execute the function in which you have written module.
Change your app.js to

```
(function(){
var app = angular.module("budgetTracker", []);

app.directive("categories", function(){
    return {

    //User Attribute directives for mixin behavior such as a tooltip, else mostly use element directives
    //Directive definition object - a configuration that defines how a directive is going to behave
        restrict: 'E', // we are declaring a new html element
        templateUrl : 'js/templates/categories.html' // url of the template to be injected
    };
});
})();
```